# Adding a column to a Pandas DataFrame as a copy

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame called *original* and I would like to add a new column to it and save the resultant DataFrame in a variable called *modified*. How do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
original = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

The solution given in the very similarly named questions here is to do something like:

```
original['c'] = original['b'].abs()
```

This does not work for me because it modifies the *original* DataFrame. A potential solution is to use join, but that does not allow me to name it nor does it allow it be filled with a scalar values:

```
modified = original.join(original['b'].abs(),rsuffix='_abs')
```

The aim is to able to add the column in a single line without temp variables to achieve the following effect:

```
modified = original.some_op() \
    .a_different_op() \
    .add_a_column() \ # <- the step I can't figure out
    .another_op() \
    .final_op()
```

Comment: Copy first then add? `modified = original.copy(); modified['c'] = ...`

Comment: Why not just use a temporary variable and rename it and/or fill it?

Comment: The why is simple. The above style avoids creating new intermediate identifiers that would be immediately discarded and makes complex data transformations easier to follow.

Comment: What do you mean immediately discarded identifiers?

Comment: I mean used once, and never touched again. @PhillipCloud, thanks btw for contributing to pandas.

Answer (score 5):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.assign` method it is described here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html