# Count consecutive missing values (nan) in more columns with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I want to count the length of time a server is stopped from a dataset. I know the downtime but not the duration.

I have this df:

```
index                   a          b     c     reboot
2018-06-25 12:51:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1      
2018-06-25 12:52:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:53:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0  
2018-06-25 12:54:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:55:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:56:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0   
2018-06-25 12:57:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0   
2018-06-25 12:58:00    NaN        0.6   0.6     0
2018-06-25 12:59:00    NaN        NaN   0.5     0  
2018-06-25 13:00:00    NaN        NaN   0.3     0  
2018-06-25 13:01:00   2.55  94.879997  0.23     0
2018-06-25 13:02:00   1.17        Nan  0.13     0
2018-06-25 13:03:00   1.08  98.199997  0.10     0
2018-06-25 13:28:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1  
2018-06-25 13:29:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0     
2018-06-25 13:30:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0
2018-06-25 13:31:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0
2018-06-25 13:31:00    0.5        0.2   0.1     0
2018-06-25 13:32:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0 
2018-06-25 13:33:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0 
2018-06-25 13:34:00     3         0.6   0.5     0
```

I want to count the rows where `a`, `b` and `c` are all `NaN` and `reboot == 1`, with the result in this form:

```
index                    period      reboot
2018-06-25 12:51:00         7           1
2018-06-25 13:28:00         4           1
```

I have already tried doing it column by column without the reboot condition.

Input:

```
index                   a          b     c     reboot
2018-06-25 12:51:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1      
2018-06-25 12:52:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:53:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0  
2018-06-25 12:54:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:55:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0    
2018-06-25 12:56:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0   
2018-06-25 12:57:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0   
2018-06-25 12:58:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0
2018-06-25 12:59:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0  
2018-06-25 13:00:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0  
2018-06-25 13:01:00   2.55  94.879997  0.23     0
2018-06-25 13:02:00   1.17        Nan  0.13     0
2018-06-25 13:03:00   1.08  98.199997  0.10     0
2018-06-25 13:28:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     1  
2018-06-25 13:29:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0     
2018-06-25 13:30:00    NaN        NaN   NaN     0
```

```py
a=df.index
b=df.b.values
idx0 = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True, np.diff(np.isnan(b))!=0,True])
count = np.diff(idx0)
idx = idx0[:-1]
valid_mask = (count>=step) & np.isnan(b[idx])
out_idx = idx[valid_mask]
out_num = a[out_idx]
out_count = count[valid_mask]
outb = zip(out_num, out_count)
periodb=list(outb)
```

Result :

```
'[(Timestamp('2018-06-25 12:51:00'), 10),
 (Timestamp('2018-06-25 13:28:00'), 3),'
```

Comment: Is always `1` in first row of only missing groups in `reboot` column?

Comment: yes the reboot started in 1 but we do not know when it ends
 just we have new values (a,b,c)and we say that the server has started

Comment: (the reboot it stops when we detect the first new value in a or b or c or all

Comment: There are 3 only NaNs columns groups (starting `12:51:00`, `13:28` and `13:32:00`), `reboot` is always 1 only for first row of this groups? Or possible e.g. in `12:54:00` ?

Comment: in the case of 13:32:00  we have just a missing values but is not a reboot because reboot==0
 the first reboot  in 12:51:00 lasted 7 minutes 12:58:00  i know the server is turned on because i have new value in b and c

Answer (score 0):

[Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722536/adding-a-column-to-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-copy) another column with "normal" indexes (integers counting up from 0), select the interesting rows, and then [find the differences between adjacent values in the added column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142967/adding-a-column-thats-result-of-difference-in-consecutive-rows-in-pandas) - since those differences will give you the distances between the rows in the original data.

Something like:

```
numbered = df.assign(row=range(len(df)))
restarts = numbered[numbered.reboot == 1]
result = restarts.row.shift(-1) - restarts.row
```

(Reading a little more closely, it seems like part of the problem is only counting the rows with NaN for all the a, b, c values. To do that, filter out all the *other* rows *first*, before adding the secondary index column.)

Comment: thank you, that gives me an idea
just (the reboot it stops when we detect the first new value in a or b or c or all